# How can I print non-sequential orders within Dynamics GP?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I'm looking to print a list of 150 or so non-sequential Purchase Orders within Dynamics GP and am hoping there is an easier solution than "manually print each order". Any help would be appreciated! I've only used the system for 4 days so far.

I've tried using Print Purchasing Documents, but I can only enter a range of POs, not a list of specific orders.